# radius of circle tangent to the parabola y=x^2

Tags: geometry, analysis, discrete-mathematics, education

In the following diagram, what's the amount of r=?

[image: Circle tangent to inside of parabola]

I supposed the center of the small circle to be $(0,y)$. So I have
its distance from $(x, x^2)$ is $(x-0)^2+(y-x^2)^2=1400^2$ this question must have just one answer so the discriminant of the equation must be zero. But then I don't have any idea. how can I relate this to the bigger circle :(

Comment: According to the rules of this site, you cannot just ask a question, without explaining the context, and/or what you have tried to solve it.  So, please add to your question, what you have tried, and where you failed / or the obstacles that you need help with.

Comment: I know just a little bit English, I am not able to explain what I have done to solve the question, sorry Sir

Comment: @reza You can make use of an online translator such as [Google Translate](https://translate.google.co.in/). You can also send a picture (though not recommended) of your mathematical work so far.

Comment: ok, I'll try my best. thanks

Comment: At the point where the circle tangent to the parabola, the normal of the parabola coincide with the radius of the circle.  Using this relationship, you can find the location of the lower circle.  See if you can get a bit further along this line of thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the lower circle of radius $1400$. Assuming its center is $(0, a)$ then its equation is

$ x^2 + (y - a)^2 = 1400^2 $

At the tangency points $y = x^2 $, therefore

$ x^2 + (x^2 - a)^2 = 1400^2 $

Expanding, this becomes,

$ x^4 + x^2 (1 - 2 a) + a^2 - 1400^2 = 0 $

Since we want only one intersection point (actually two, but a single value of $x^2$), the discriminant must be zero, hence

$ (1 - 2 a)^2 - 4 (a^2 - 1400^2 ) = 0 $

Simplifying this becomes

$ 1 - 4 a + 4 (1400^2 ) = 0 $

From which,

$ a = \dfrac{ 1 + 4 (1400^2) }{4} = 1400^2 + \dfrac{1}{4} $

Now, we can move to the upper circle, its center is at $( 0, a + r )$ and radius $r$, thus its equation is

$ x^2 + ( y - (a + r) )^2 = r^2$

Again at the points of tangency, $y = x^2 $, so

$ x^2 + (x^2 - (a + r) )^2 = r^2 $

which simplifies to

$ x^4 + x^2 (1 - 2 (a + r) ) + (a + r)^2 - r^2 = 0 $

And we want the value of $x^2$ that solves this quadratic to be a single value, so again, the discriminant must be zero,

$ ( 1 - 2(a + r) )^2 - 4 ( a^2 + 2 a r ) = 0 $

Expanding,

$ 1 - 4 (a + r) + 4 (a^2 + 2 a r + r^2 ) - 4 (a^2 + 2 a r ) = 0 $

and this simplifies to

$ 1 - 4 (a + r) + 4 r^2 = 0 $

Knowing $a$ from the first circle, we can proceed to solve for $r$, there will be two values, and we should take the positive one. The other negative value corresponds to the circle that can drawn tangent to the '$1400$' circle but from below.

Can you take it from here ?

Comment: Great, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an inscribed circle $\gamma$ of centre $C$ and tangency point $P=(x,x^2)$. The tangent at $P$ intersects $x$-axis at $M=(x/2,0)$ (easy to prove property of a parabola). If $H$ and $K$ are the projections of $P$ on cartesian axes, triangles $PHM$ and $PKC$ are similar (because $CP\perp PM$), hence:
$$
d:{x\over2}=r:\sqrt{x^4+{x^2\over4}}=x:x^2,
$$
where $d=CK$ and $r=CP$ is the radius of $\gamma$. It follows that:
$$
d={1\over2}
\quad\text{and}\quad
r=\sqrt{x^2+{1\over4}}.
$$
Hence:
$$OC=x^2+{1\over2}=r^2+{1\over4}.$$

If we have a larger circle $\gamma'$, tangent to the parabola and to $\gamma$, with center $O'$ and radius $r'$, we have then:

$$OC'=r'^2+{1\over4}.$$

But $CC'=r+r'$, that is:
$$
r'^2-r^2=r'+r,
\quad\text{whence:}\quad
r'-r=1.
$$

[image]

If the equation of the parabola were instead $y=ax^2$, we would obviously get:
$$r'-r={1\over a}.$$